# Mysql high number of queries in queue

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb

we have been struggling to understand this behabiour on mariadb. we have some jobs that run every minute and they do a lot of updates on some metadata tables inside mariadb, however we have noticed that simple updates where id=X are taking more than 5 seconds, and when we get the show engine innodb status we get the following:

```
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
16 queries inside InnoDB, 266 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
51 RW transactions active inside InnoDB
0 RO transactions active inside InnoDB
51 out of 1000 descriptors used
Main thread process no. 389, id 139921595545344, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 2770109, updated 5194512, deleted 907329, read 35768640153
1.36 inserts/s, 69.81 updates/s, 0.64 deletes/s, 923868.28 reads/s
Number of system rows inserted 0, updated 0, deleted 0, read 0
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
```

We think that the CPU is strugling to handle all 300 updates at the same time. Can you please help me understand this behaviour?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, the 'simple' `UPDATE`, any likely queries that might be running at the same time.  (I will probably request further info.)  A lot of different things could be leading to what you are seeing; it will take some digging to isolate the issue.  Meanwhile, yes, 300/sec is border-line for HDD drives; or do you have SSDs?  Also, what is the setting of `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit?

Comment: Another thing...  Describe the "queuing mechanism.  Cron?  Events?  Something else?  Would my mantra apply:  "Don't queue it, just do it"?

Comment: Please post results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'uptime'; so we have idea how long it took to read 35 Billion rows.  Your complete report from SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; posted to pastebin.com would probably be very enlightening.  Please post results of SELECT @@VERSION; so we know the version of MaridDB you are using.